# Web Pages Layout page

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and trying to create a simple application that inserts records into the database using ASP.NET Web Pages. I have a file called Post.cshtml that contains the form. I have noticed at the top that there's a commented code block to specify the layout for this page. Do I need a different layout page for this one because I can already view the contents of the page in the browser. Why would I need another layout for this? Or does this serve a different purpose? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layouts used for separating common data from specific page. Let's say you have header, menu, content and footer. Header, menu and footer will be same for all pages, so you move them to layout and your specific page will have content.

You can check this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/layouts) for more info about layouts

Answer (score 0):

Basically, **Layouts are used to provide consistent layout across pages in application**. Its similar to `MasterPage` in web forms. In ASP.Net MVC, you can specify layout page in `.cshtml` file itself or in `_viewstart.cshtml` file if you want to apply common layout to all the views in particular folder.

In your case, it may be the case that, developer has specified it in `_viewstart.cshtml` and commented out the line on the page. So, if layout and rendering of the page is as you are expecting, you don't need to specify layout page. But, if you want different layout for that page, you can.

In addition to the resource provided by @Uriil, you can learn about layouts [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts)